# How to format a dataframe in Python with multiple columns but a single row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in Python which consists of 1 row but 100 columns. It looks like this:

```
_id  d.0.id  d.0.name  d.0.dep.id  d.0.dep.name  d.0.dep.1.id  d.0.dep.1.name .... 

 A     B        C          D            E            F            G
```

I need to transform the dataframe to a csv file in the following manner:

```
_id  d.0.id  d.0.name  d.dep.id   d.dep.name

 A     B        C          D           E
 A     B        C          F           G
 .     .        .          .           .
 .     .        .          .           .
```

The new csv file should have 5 columns. The first three columns should contain the same entries throughout the file. Only the last two columns change in each row. Please tell me how I can perform this type of dataframe manipulation in Python using Pandas.

Comment: Do you mean only the first five columns should be exported to csv?

Comment: You can try a `for` loop, accessing `d.0.dep.i.id...` for each of your  every 5 columns and put that in a new data frame of 5 columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a new dataframe with these 5 columns:

```
df1 = df.iloc[:,0:5]
or
df1=df[[_id,d.0.id,d.0.name,d.dep.id,d.dep.name]]
```

Save the new dataframe as csv:

```
df1.to_csv('./file_path')
```

**Solution for the Extended Question**

Convert the single row to ndarray

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('df_info.txt', sep=",", header=0)
vallist=df.as_matrix()[0]
```

output:

```
array(['NBA', 'Mens', 'Sports', 'LAL', 'Lakers', 'BOS', 'Celtics', 'SAS',
       'Spurs', 'OKC', 'Thunder'], dtype=object)
```

Create a Dict to store the values

```
dict={}
n=4
varlist1=[]
for i in range(len(vallist)):
    if(n<=9):
        dict[i]={}
        print(vallist[n],vallist[n+1])
        dict[i]['col1']=vallist[0]
        dict[i]['col2']=vallist[1]
        dict[i]['col3']=vallist[2]
        dict[i]['col4']=vallist[n]
        dict[i]['col5']=vallist[n+1]
        n+=2
```

Import the dict to Dataframe

```
df2=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict)
df2.transpose()
```

**Final Result:**

```
   col1 col2    col3    col4    col5
0   NBA Mens    Sports  Lakers  BOS
1   NBA Mens    Sports  Celtics SAS
2   NBA Mens    Sports  Spurs   OKC
```

Comment: Thank you! That formed the required new csv file format. Could you please suggest a way to populate the new csv file quickly? The other tedious method is populating it manually, by adding new rows one by one.

Comment: @AkshayVenkatesh to_csv populates the csv file, what other method you are looking?

Comment: When I export to csv, only the first row is formed properly. However I need another approximately 46 rows for the remaining 98 column names. For example, I have got     A     B      C     D      E as first row. I need the second row now as     A     B      C     F     G.   Similarly the third row should have the first three column values the same, but the last two column values different. I could manually populate these new rows, but is there a faster method to populate them?

Comment: Is it possible to share some sample data to work on?

Comment: Please give me a couple of minutes to share the data online.

Comment: I can't disclose the data I have but I can share similar data. The data I have is in the form:                                                                                                                 NBA  Mens  Sports LAL Lakers  BOS Celtics  SAS  Spurs  OKC Thunder ..    I need the new format as:  NBA Mens Sports LAL Lakers.                            Next row: NBA Mens Sports BOS Celtics.                                                       Next row: NBA Mens Sports SAS Spurs, and so on. The first row is formed properly, I'm wondering if the other rows can be formed quickly.

Comment: what's ur email? let's talk there, I can solve it tonight.

Comment: My email is lalakv0824@gmail.com. Thank you very much for your consistent replies!